# Update corresponding object on multiple jquery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of objects I would like to initiate an ajax request for each, and the result of that request should be stored in the corresponding object for that request

say I have

```js
var dataArray = [{url,data},{url,data},{url,data},{url,data}];
for (var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    $.get( dataArray[i].url, function() {
        .done(function() {
            //update dataArray[i].data
        })
        .fail(function() {
            //update dataArray[i].data
        })
    });
}
```

what is the proper way to do this

p.s: I don't want to use async: false as I want to update the status bar

---

update

It did worked out like this

```
var dataArray = [{url,data},{url,data},{url,data},{url,data}];
for (var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    $.get( dataArray[i].url, function() {
        .done(function(Data) {
            dataArray[i].data = data
        })
        .fail(function() {
            //Error handling
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried : `$.get( dataArray[i].url, function(newData) { dataArray[i].data = newData; })`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. As you pass the object reference, when you update data it should update the original array. Sorry I'm not providing a jsbin, have blocked at work.

```
function loopThrough() {
  var dataArray = [{url,data},{url,data},{url,data},{url,data}];
  dataArray.forEach(function(element) {
    getData(element)
  })
}

function getData(element) {
  $.get( element.url)
     .done(function() {
        //update element.data
    })
    .fail(function() {
        //update element.data
    })
});
}
```

Comment: That's seems to work, however I figured out an easier way to do it

Comment: Can you please post that easier way. I don't see many conventional alternative to what me or @Chris_Dixon posted.

Comment: I did post it as an update, please refer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your `.get` functions in their own functions with the dataArray[i] passed in.

```
var dataArray = [{url,data},{url,data},{url,data},{url,data}];
for (var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
   $(function(data) {
      $.get(data.url, function() {
      })
      .done(function() {
          //update data.data
      })
      .fail(function() {
          //update data.data
      })
    });
   }, dataArray[i]);
}
```